# Colliding black holes to an outside observer

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, singularities, gravitational-waves

We know that a particle approaching an event horizon will appear to an outside observer to slow down and never cross the horizon.

What is observed by an outside observer when a singularity approaches/crosses another event horizon?  What happens to the propagation of gravitational waves? (Is the wave propagation affected by the time-dilation near the horizon?)

Comment: [What does a binary black hole merger look like?](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7775)